# How to change colour and position of Navbar using useEffect and useState?

Tags: reactjs

I try to give new functionality to this Navbar
https://reactstrap.github.io/?path=/docs/components-navbar--navbar
first I want it to change Color after scrolling down;

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const [colorChange, setColorChange] = useState(false);

useEffect( () => 
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
  let newWidth = window.innerWidth;
    let newHeight = window.innerHeight; 
if(newHeight =< 300) {setColorChange={false}}
else {setColorChange={true}
}, [])

{colorChange ?    <Navbar className="navbar-expand-lg h6-nav-bar"
           fixed="top"
           color="dark"
           > : <Navbar className="navbar-expand-lg h6-nav-bar"> }
```

Please indicate my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

```
    {setColorChange={false}}
    else {setColorChange={true}
```

setColorChange is a function so you should call this, not assign value

```
setColorChange(false) // like this
```

Comment: After that I have another error:````  <container> { formula } </container>```
Syntax error: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <Navbar>.

Comment: You can check the {} tag, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-eyyvnb this link here might help

Comment: It works partially, because I try to look into console and then it change background, but after close console it still is the same value. 
I thought that I should something put into [] to be observed, but do not know what.

Answer (score 0):

I  was an idiot, I use 'resize' instead of 'scroll'.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const updateWindowDimensions = () => {
    if(window.scrollY >= 300) {
      setColorChange(true);
    } else {
      setColorChange(false);   
  };
  };

  window.addEventListener("scroll", updateWindowDimensions);

  return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", updateWindowDimensions) 

}, []);
```